# What is the time format string for this date: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 11:55:55 GMT

Tags: java, android

I need to create a SimpleDateFormat in order to parse this date and convert it to another format but I dont know how to pass it into the constructor:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("???");
```

Comment: EEE, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss z

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `SimpleDateFormat`? What have you tried? Hint: create a Date object (using f.e. `new Date()` to get the current date) and format it using the `SimpleDateFormat`instance to check that it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date format should be

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

Here is a DateFormat cheat sheet:

[image]

Comment: will accept in 7 minutes, as you were the first to answer. thanks

Comment: This solution will throw ParseException on any system whose Locale is not English, because "Sat" will not be understandable.
Therefore, I'd suggest :  `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

Where

- E = Day in week
- d = Day in month
- M = Month in year
- y = Year
- H = Hour in day
- m = Minute in hour
- s = Second in minute
- z = Time zone

For more info see [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Sat, 26 Jul 2014 11:55:55 GMT"
 "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
```

Answer (score 0):

sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);